# MLKit Error: Failed to load model from path mlkit_pose/pose_person_detector_f16.tflite

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I made an Unity plugin for Android that uses MLKit. Everything works fine untill the MLKit pose detector is analyzing the image:

```
        Task<Pose> result =
                _pd.process(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(
                                new OnSuccessListener<Pose>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Pose pose) {
                                        Log.i("MyComppany", "trig OnSuccessListener!");
                                    }
                                })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.i("MyComppany", "trig OnFailureListener!");
                                        Log.i("MyComppany", String.valueOf(e));
                                    }
                                });
```

after which I get this error:

```
03-30 12:16:47.318 13171 13171 I MyCompany   : com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Mediapipe failed with message: internal: Graph has errors: 
03-30 12:16:47.318 13171 13171 I MyCompany   : Calculator::Open() for node "posetrackingsubgraph__posedetectionsubgraph__TfLiteInferenceCalculator" failed: RET_CHECK failure (third_party/mediapipe/util/tflite/tflite_model_loader.cc:70) model Failed to load model from path mlkit_pose/pose_person_detector_f16.tflite
```

This suggests that the tfile was lost when building the plugin but I am not sure how to debug this further. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because I literally didn't have the specified model file. Since I was using an `AAR` plugin, I had to download all the underlying dependencies into Unity's `Assets/Plugins/Android` using `unity-jar-resolver`. After I did so, I was experiencing a dependency collision, which forced me to delete that dependency `("com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:17.0.1-beta3")`. In the end, it turned out that I had only a reference of `"com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:17.0.1-beta3"` in the Unity Plugin, not the whole contents.

As a workaround, I exported my project into Android Studio and added `"com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:17.0.1-beta3"` into Gradle. Everything works now.